# iOS SDK 8.1 deployment target 7.1 on Xcode 6 - View compressed and other issues with auto layout

Tags: ios, xcode, view, sdk, autolayout

really need some help here.
I built an application on Xcode 6 iOS SDK 8.1. 
When testing on iOS 8.1 everything works perfectly. But when I test it on an iOS 7.1 the auto layout is messed up and, most importantly the view is compressed on the iPhone 5.

How do I make my app work on iOS 7.1 the way it works for 8.1??